# Using a statically compiled C file as rootfs

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, u-boot, rootfs

I want to boot my imx53-qsb board using not a normal rootfs but a **statically** compiled *hello_world.c* file in other words a *hello_world_static.out*.
To achieve that, I wrote a *hello_world.c* file cross compiled it statically and I put it in my **mmcblk0p1 ext4** partition of my sd card. I put my *uImage* and my *u-boot.imx* in the mmcblk0. After booting my system I got a **kernel panic** :

> Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.

Any solution ? Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code of your `hello_world.c` file. Also tell us which exactly toolchain you are using for building it.

Comment: @SamProtsenko here is my hello_world.c code ` #include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
} ` I compiled it with _gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux_

Answer (score 1):

You should provide `init=` param to kernel cmdline (from u-boot). For example, if your binary file name is `init` and you have put it to `/sbin` directory (on your rootfs partition), you should add `init=/sbin/init` to your kernel cmdline in u-boot (in `bootargs` variable).

For example you can do next (in u-boot shell, before running `bootm` or `booti` command):

```
setenv bootargs root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext4 init=/sbin/init
```

Also, check if you really have your rootfs on `mmcblk0p1`. Usually `mmcblk0p1` is FAT32 partition which contains bootloader files and images to copy to RAM. Rootfs is usually located on `mmcblk0p2` (and formatted as ext4).

For details see:

[1] [Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) (look for `init=` param)

[2] [u-boot README file](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob_plain;f=README;hb=HEAD) (look for `Boot Linux:` line)

[3] [Documentation/init.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/init.txt)

Comment: @samprotsenkok Thanks for those links ! But what I want is not having the rootfs in my partition, only a static compile hello_world file. I tried to modify u-boot bootargs like this : _optargs=quiet init=/hello_world_static.out_ and _mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=${mmcroot} rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype} ${optargs}_ but still not work.

Comment: @samprotsenkok here is my u-boot environment variables : _bootargs_base=setenv bootargs console=ttymxc0,115200_ **AND** _bootargs_mmc=root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext4 init=/hello_s.out_ **AND** _bootcmd_mmc=run bootargs_base bootargs_mmc;mmc dev 0;mmc read ${loadaddr} 0x800 0x4000;bootm_ **AND** _bootcmd=run bootcmd_mmc_ When I boot with those parameters, I got a different error : _Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:_

Comment: @EngineerN Yeah, I wasn't actually saying anything about actual rootfs, but you still need some partition called `rootfs` formatted as `ext4`. Any your rootfs is basically just that one file of yours.

Comment: @EngineerN Try this: `setenv bootargs console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext4 init=/hello_s.out`, and then run your boot command. Also, are you sure that your first partition is where your binary resides?

Comment: Ah ok. I just tried what you said but I still got the same error. Yes I am sure, I formatted the partition as ext4. When I put a "normal" rootfs it works well. Thank you for your help man ;)

Comment: What do you mean "the same error"? Which exactly, `invalid root=` or `invalid init=`?

Comment: This one _error : Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:_ Any idea ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it worth to add `rootwait` param to cmdline (i.e. to `bootargs` variable in u-boot). Also check that you have correct `root=` param in your kernel cmdline (somewhere at the top of kernel log output, look for `Kernel command line:` text). Here is my cmdline to run my board: `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw console=ttyO2,115200 init=/init rootfstype=ext4 rootwait`.

Comment: I put this _setenv bootargs_mmc root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait init=/hello_s.out_  but on the log in the kernel command line there is a problem : _Unknown command 'root=/dev/mmcblk0p1' - try 'help'_ Can we move to the chat to talk about it ? or you prefer staying here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79035/discussion-between-sam-protsenko-and-engineern).